# How do I force mkdir to overwrite existing directory?

Tags: java

I need to have my program create a directory with a specific name, and overwrite any existing directory with that name. Currently, my program doesn't seem to be able to overwrite the directory. Is there any way of forcing the overwrite?

```
private boolean makeDirectory(){
    File file = new File(TEMP_DIR_PATH + "/" + clipName);
    if (file.mkdir()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Failed to create directory!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Now I'm trying the following, but the program is not detecting that the directory exists, even though it does.

```
private boolean makeDirectory(String path){
    File file = new File(path);
    if (file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("exists");
        if (file.delete()) {
            System.out.println("deleted");
        }
    }
    if (file.mkdir()) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        System.err.println("Failed to create directory!");
        return false;
    }
}
```

RESOLVED:
(If anyone else in the future needs to know...)
I ended up doing it this way:

```
private boolean makeDirectory(String path){
    if (Files.exists(Paths.get(path))) {
        try {
            FileUtils.deleteDirectory(new File(path));
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed to create directory!");
            return false;
        }
    }    
    if (new File(path).mkdir()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why? If it already exists, why recreate it? Do you mean you need to *clear* it before use?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You want to delete the directory first if it exists, then recreate it.

[Using `java.nio.file.Files`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

```
if (Files.exists(path)) {
    new File("/dir/path").delete();
} 

new File("/dir/path").mkdir();
```

and if you have [FileUtils, this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#cleanDirectory(java.io.File)) might be preferable as it avoids actually deleting a directory you want to be there:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils

if (Files.exists(path)) {
    FileUtils.cleanDirectory( new File("/dir/path"));
} else {
    new File("/dir/path").mkdir();
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this, but Files.exists() requires:

public static boolean exists(Path path,
             LinkOption... options)

so I'm using the exist() function from File instead, but I'm still having problems. I posted updated code above. Any suggestions?

Comment: @labananala use java.nio.file.Files

Comment: Thanks! This was really helpful. I had to use FileUtils.deleteDirectory() so that I could recursively delete the directory (File.delete() can't delete unless the directory is empty).

Answer (score 2):

You can import this library `import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;` and then you could write your code like this:

```
private boolean makeDirectory(){
    File file = new File(TEMP_DIR_PATH + "/" + clipName);
    boolean returnValue = false;
    try {
         FileUtils.forceMkdir(file);
         returnValue = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
         throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: I don't believe forceMkdir overwrites an existing directory, it will create it if it doesn't already exist, or else it will do nothing if it is already an existing directory.

Answer (score -2):

1. Check if the directory exists,
   If so, delete that directory
2. Create directory

Comment: Captain Obvious strikes again